# redirect all requests of domain a to corrosponding page of domain b

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

hello all i have a domain a where my site is and now i have a short domain of my main site b i want to diect all the trafics from domain b to domain a like

```
www.b.com/xyz.php?id=23 to www.a.com/xyz.php?id=23
```

and this all by htaccess only right now i am using index page with this code

```
 header('location:www.domain.com');
```

if you have any idea please let me know
any help is appreciated 
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its going in .htaccess of your doc root, then a simple rewrite should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.b\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.a.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This assumes you have the Rewrite module loaded in the main config file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a rewrite condition where you check the hostname and if it equals to domain b, you redirect the user to domain a.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.b\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.a.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `R=301` will tell the webserver to send a `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` header. The `L` stands for `Last` and will make apache stop trying to look for further matching rewrite rules.